# XSLT трансформация

Tags: xml, xslt

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns:sql="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-sql">
    <P xmlns="ExternalPriceCBO"
                PID="208"
                PN="ТСК Мульти-Брянск [208]">
        <CG CGID="56"
                    CGN="Форд"
                    O="0"
                    CGNEng="Ford">
            <CT CTID="1574"
                        CTN="Focus C346 MCA FC"
                        O="0"
                        CTNEng="Focus C346 MCA FC">
                <CM CMID="8101"
                            CMN="Ford Focus C346 MCA FC Седан 1,6 л, 105 л.с., МКП5, 4дв., Trend (SYNC Edition) (L4X1) белый"
                            Without_Code_Car_Model_Name="Ford Focus C346 MCA FC Седан 1,6 л, 105 л.с., МКП5, 4дв., Trend (SYNC Edition)"
                            Engine_Type=""
                            PTS_Name="Ford Focus"
                            Complectation="Trend (SYNC Edition)"
                            CMNEng="Ford Focus C346 MCA FC Седан 1,6 л, 105 л.с., МКП5, 4дв., Trend (SYNC Edition) (L4X1) белый"
                            CMID_E="f7162ebe-2ad5-11e5-8021-e8393521650c">
                    <Co CoN="белый"
                                CoMet="Нет"
                                CoID="FRWH">
                        <Cfg N="16&quot; стальные диски с декоративными колпаками Trend; Tтрёхточечные ремни безопасности для всех пассажиров
                                                на заднем ряду;  "
                                    T=""
                                    MIDR="810"
                                    MSR="R"
                                    PrR="961000"
                                    Year="0"
                                    CoSalonN="C DARK CHAR BLACK"
                                    CoSalonID="CDCB"
                                    PrRBase="961000"
                                    PrRDop="0">
                            <A AID="1"
                                        AV="0"/>
                            <A AID="2"
                                        AV="4"/>
                            <A AID="10"
                                        AV="0">
                                <O OID="c8ce8360-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="16&quot; стальные диски с декоративными колпаками Trend"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c8ce8352-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Tтрёхточечные ремни безопасности для всех пассажиров на заднем ряду"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c8ce8348-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Антиблокировочная система тормозов (ABS) с системой распределения тормозных усилий (EBD)"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c8ce8368-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Аудиосистема CD/MP3 + AM/FM,  6 динамиков, 3,5&quot; матричный дисплей, USB/AUX"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="БЦ"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Базовая цена а/м"
                                            OISO="0"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c1c95915-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Бамперы, окрашенные в цвет кузова"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c1c95917-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Боковые зеркала окрашенные в цвет кузова с индикатором поворота и электрорегулировкой"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c8ce8362-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Боковые зеркала с обогревом"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c8ce8332-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Два открытых подстаканника"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c8ce8344-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Задние дисковые тормоза"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c8ce83b0-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Задние электростеклоподъемники"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c8ce835a-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Иммобилайзер"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c8ce83ae-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Карманы в спинках передних сидений"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c8ce832c-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Компактное запасное колесо"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c8ce8366-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Кондиционер"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="461"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Кондиционер"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c8ce8340-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Крепления для детских сидений ISOFIX"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c8ce8338-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Освещаемый перчаточный ящик"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c8ce835e-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Передние противотуманные фары"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c8ce83b8-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Передние сидения с подогревом"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c8ce832e-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Передние электростеклоподъемники"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c8ce833c-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Подголовники для всех пассажиров (5)"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c8ce833e-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Регулировка водительского сидения по высоте"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c8ce8350-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Ремни безопасности регулируемые по высоте"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c8ce83b6-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Розетка 12В в центральном боксе"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c8ce8334-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Розетка 12В и USB на передней панели"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c8ce83ac-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Рукоятка рычага переключения передач с кожаной отделкой (для АКП)"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c8ce833a-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Рулевая колонка, регулируемая по вылету и углу наклона"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c8ce835c-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Ручки дверей окрашенные в цвет кузова"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c8ce8346-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Световая индикация об экстренном торможении"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="41fd0d4e-a5b5-11e6-80f0-001f29ef4216"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Система &quot;ЭРА-ГЛОНАСС&quot;"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c8ce8358-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Система Ford My Key ®"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c8ce836a-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Система Ford SYNC 1-го поколения, включая Bluetooth и голосовое управление на русском языке"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c8ce834c-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Система помощи при трогании на подъеме (HLA)"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c8ce8336-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Солнцезащитные козырьки с встроенными зеркалами"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c8ce8342-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Спинка заднего сидения складывающиеся в пропорции 60/40"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c8ce8330-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Указатель температуры окружающей среды"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c8ce834e-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Фирменная система заправки Ford Easy Fuel без использования крышки заливной горловины"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c8ce8354-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Фронтальные подушки безопасности для водителя и переднего пассажира"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c8ce83b2-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Функция автоматического закрывания передних стекол при запирании автомобиля"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c8ce8364-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Хромированные внутренние ручки дверей"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c8ce83b4-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Центральный бокс с подлокотником"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c8ce8356-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Центральный замок с дистанционным управлением"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="c8ce834a-2b06-11e5-8021-e8393521650c"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Электронная система курсовой устойчивости (ESP), включая антипробуксовочную систему (TC) и систему помощи при экстренном торможении (EBA)"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                            </A>
                            <A AID="30"
                                        AV="0">
                                <O OID="FRWH"
                                            ONS="белый"
                                            ONL="белый"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                                <O OID="68BF"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Пакет &quot;Комфорт&quot;: Двухзонный климат-контроль, авто-затемняющееся салонное зеркало заднего вида, датчик света, датчик дождя, функц"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                            </A>
                            <A AID="20"
                                        AV="0">
                                <O OID="CDCB"
                                            ONS=""
                                            ONL="Тканевая отделка салона - черная"
                                            OISO="1"
                                            OO="0"/>
                            </A>
                            <VIN>Z6F4XXEEC4HU27959</VIN>
                            <LGST>0</LGST>
                            <APPDATEOFARR>2017/2/25</APPDATEOFARR>
                            <ComNum>7MTZ</ComNum>
                        </Cfg>
                    </Co>
                    <ENGCAP>1,6</ENGCAP>
                    <ENGHP>105</ENGHP>
                    <TRANS>МКП5</TRANS>
                    <bodytype>Седан</bodytype>
                    <CARDRV>Передний</CARDRV>
                    <FUELTP>Бензиновый</FUELTP>
                    <MODCODE>L4X1</MODCODE>
                    <PRKNG/>
                </CM>
```

Это часть XML файла мне надо выдернуть из него данные в новый файл XML через XSLT, так вот как добраться до VIN ? что надо прописать в value-of select где сейчас //* , или я вообще не правильно делаю? помогите пожалуйста

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" cdata-section-elements="Description AdditionalEquipment" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
<root>
 <xsl:for-each select="//*">
<Vin>
            <xsl:value-of select="VIN"/>
 </Vin>

</xsl:for-each>
</root>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В показанном xml нет элемента с именем `VIN`. Но есть элемент с именем `{ExternalPriceCBO}VIN`. Пространства имён нужно обязательно учитывать! Это как фамилия у человека.

Соответственно, добавляем определение неймспейса (я дал ему префикс `CBO` - можете выбрать любой другой) и далее используем его.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
                xmlns:CBO="ExternalPriceCBO">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" cdata-section-elements="Description AdditionalEquipment" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <xsl:for-each select="//CBO:VIN">
        <Vin>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </Vin>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
                xmlns:CBO="ExternalPriceCBO">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" cdata-section-elements="Description AdditionalEquipment" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
<root>
      <xsl:for-each select="//CBO:CM">           
        <xsl:variable name="Year">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="Year != '' and Year != '0' and Year != 0">
              <xsl:value-of select="Year"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="'2018'"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>


<Car>
<BodyType>
<xsl:value-of select="CBO:bodytype"/>  
</BodyType>
<Make>
<xsl:value-of select="@PTS_Name"/>    
</Make>
<Model>
<xsl:value-of select="@PTS_Name"/>    
</Model>
<ModificationName>
<xsl:value-of select="@Without_Code_Car_Model_Name"/>   
</ModificationName>
<ComplName>
<xsl:value-of select="@Complectation"/>
</ComplName>
<CompCode>
<xsl:value-of select="CBO:MODCODE"/> 
 </CompCode>
  <Color>
<xsl:value-of select="CBO:Co/@CoN"/>
</Color>
<Year>
<xsl:value-of select="CBO:Co//@Year"/>
</Year>
<Price>
<xsl:value-of select="CBO:Co//@PrR"/>
</Price>
<PriceEP>
<xsl:value-of select="CBO:Co//@PrRBase"/>
</PriceEP>
<SpecialPrice>
<xsl:value-of select="CBO:Co//@PrRDop"/>
</SpecialPrice>
<Currency>
<xsl:value-of select="CBO:Co//@MSR"/>
</Currency>
<VIN>
</VIN>
<EngineSize>
<xsl:value-of select="CBO:ENGCAP"/>
</EngineSize>       
<FuelType>
<xsl:value-of select="CBO:FUELTP"/> 
 </FuelType>
<Enginepower>
<xsl:value-of select="CBO:ENGHP"/> 
</Enginepower>
<Transmission>
<xsl:value-of select="CBO:TRANS"/> 
</Transmission>
<Drive>
<xsl:value-of select="CBO:CARDRV"/>    
</Drive>
<City>
</City>
<Car-location>
<xsl:value-of select="CBO:PRKNG"/> 
</Car-location>
<Equipment>
<xsl:value-of select="CBO:Co//@ONL"/>
</Equipment>
<Description>
<xsl:value-of select="CBO:Co//@N"/>
</Description>
</Car>
</xsl:for-each>
</root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Вот я начал использовать CBO как вы и сказали , но все равно возникли трудности я не могу добраться до VIN хотя он по сути лежит CM/Co/Cfg/VIN

Вот так не работает, его можно вызвать?

Comment: `CBO:Co/CBO:Cfg/CBO:VIN`

Comment: Спасибо все работает и последний вопрос)можно как нибудь из этого вытащить только слово Ford или Focus??? ' CMN="Ford Focus C346 MCA FC Седан 1,6 л, 105 л.с., МКП5, 4дв., Trend (SYNC Edition) (L4X1) белый"  '

Comment: Не задавайте вопросы вместо ответов. И уж тем более не задавайте вопросы в комментариях. Или отредактируйте вопрос, или (что лучше) задайте новый.